# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, Compile AOSP

Tags: android, windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to compile AOSP code using the new WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) aka Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. I have successfully setup my build environment and sync'd AOSP code.

I am unable to get "make" to complete a build for even just a single app.

[Attached is a strace file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7a9Uly-yQCZTGktSU5yTS1yekk/view?usp=sharing). Make seems to hang when reading the file "build/core/clang/TARGET_arm.mk" (this file is initialized on line 1443 of the trace), although this file is successfully read several times prior to the hang.

Any ideas about what is causing make to hang? How can I dig deeper to find out what is causing the hang?

Comment: This is the issue that MS needs fixing: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/498

Answer (score 3):

Ehm, yeah, that was the only thing I've wanted to do with the bash since 30th of March when it was announced. I tried it out by myself and I also read an article at xda-developers four months ago that it currently isn't possible to successfully compile Android using this subsystem due to some missing dependencies. There's currently no solution to do that. We have to hope for an update which gives us this awesome possibility. Even if it'll work some day you will have to expect twice the build time you have on a normal Ubuntu setup. Anyway, the bash development is progressing so I'm full of hope it'll work in some months...